# Inverse of Imaginary Error Function

Tags: inverse, error-function

Is there a closed-form formula for inverse of *imaginary* error function? It would be nice to have it through erf and inverse erf.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{erfi}^{-1}(x) = -i \, \text{erf}^{-1}(i x)
$$
You can show this by considering the definition of the imaginary inverse function
$$
\text{erfi}(x) = -i\,\text{erf}(i x)
$$
I hope this is what you needed.